# Syntax error on IF EXISTS

Tags: database, syntax-error, mysql-workbench, privileges

Im having some trouble in drop user with `if exists` statement in MySQL Workbench. The error is

```
Syntax error : unexpected if.
```

[image]

Comment: What is the version of the server you connected to? MySQL Workbench can dynamically switch language features based on the server version.

Answer (score 0):

The `IF EXISTS` syntax for `DROP USER` was a new feature in MySQL 5.7. It was not implemented in MySQL 5.6.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/drop-user.html says:

> As of MySQL 5.7.8, the IF EXISTS clause can be used, which causes the statement to produce a warning for each named account that does not exist, rather than an error.

It's possible that MySQL Workbench has not caught up to this syntax. You can try to upgrade to the latest version of MySQL Workbench, and hope that they have updated it.

Or you can try putting the new clause into a version-specific comment:

```
DROP USER /*!50708 IF EXISTS */ ...
```

This comment syntax MySQL uses to protect syntax that isn't supported by earlier versions. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html for explanation.